# How can I describe the Cartesian unit vectors in-terms of the Polar unit vectors?

Tags: polar-coordinates

The unit vectors in polar coordinates describe the directions of increasing $\rho$ and $\phi$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\hat \rho &= \cos(\phi) \hat i + \sin(\phi) \hat j \\
\hat \phi &= -\sin(\phi) \hat i + \cos(\phi) \hat j \\
\end{align*}
$$

Note the above formulas give the polar unit vectors in-terms of the cartesian unit vectors $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. This somewhat bothers me, since it doesn't seem like there should be anything "fundamental" about cartesian coordinates. Why can't I start with polar coordinates and describe the cartesian unit vectors in terms of $\hat \rho$ and $\hat \phi$?

$$
\begin{align*}
\hat i &= ?\ \hat \rho\ + ?\ \hat \phi \\
\hat j &= ?\ \hat \rho\ + ?\ \hat \phi \\
\end{align*}
$$

I think that, given $\hat \rho$ and $\hat \phi$, (both of which depend on $\phi$ - or where I am in the plane), I can rotate clockwise by $\phi$ to obtain $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. This rotation is given (in the standard basis) by the matrix:
$$R(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \phi & \sin \phi \\ -\sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix}.$$
So, for example, to get $\hat i$, I want to rotate $\hat \rho$ by $\phi$ radians. But if I want to apply $R(\phi)$ to $\hat \rho$, I need to express $\hat \rho$ in the standard basis again, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{bmatrix} \hat{\rho} \\ \hat{\phi} \end{bmatrix}=R(\phi)\begin{bmatrix} \hat{i} \\ \hat{j}\end{bmatrix}$$
Now multiply by $(R(\phi))^{-1}$.